# Linking values between datasets

Tags: regex, r

I have a bit of a pickle here. I need to automate filling cells in with repetitive which has duplicates, and isn't in order. I'm sure that isn't very clear.

In a biology study, there are x number of individuals. Information like the Sex and Weight of the individual stays consistent throughout the course of the study:

```
| Ind | S | W | 
| 1   | M | 4 |
| 2   | M | 6 |
| 3   | F | 2 |
| 4   | M | 8 |
| 5   | F | 4 |
| 6   | F | 3 |
...
```

There were certain measurements which were taken from individual test subjects multiple times. Right now I have two spread sheets. One that has the consistent values, like the ones listed above, and one that has multiple values (samples A and B below) per individual:

```
| Ind |  A | B | 
|   1 | .1 | 4 |
|   1 | .2 | 6 |
|   1 | .1 | 2 |
|   1 | .3 | 8 |
|   2 | .1 | 4 |
|   2 | .1 | 3 |
|   2 | .3 | 4 |
|   3 | .2 | 6 |
|   3 | .2 | 2 |
|   3 | .1 | 8 |
|   3 | .1 | 4 |
|   3 | .1 | 3 |
```

Basically, before I start running stats on these data, I want to fill in the consistent values on the multiple sample worksheet, and I'd really like to avoid doing manually as the data sets are much longer than this. The end results would look something like this:

```
| Ind | A  | B | S | W | 
| 1   | .1 | 4 | M | 4 |
| 1   | .2 | 6 | M | 4 |
| 1   | .1 | 2 | M | 4 |
| 1   | .3 | 8 | M | 4 |
| 2   | .1 | 4 | M | 6 |
| 2   | .1 | 3 | M | 6 |
| 2   | .3 | 4 | M | 6 |
| 3   | .2 | 6 | F | 2 |
| 3   | .2 | 2 | F | 2 |
| 3   | .1 | 8 | F | 2 |
| 3   | .1 | 4 | F | 2 |
| 3   | .1 | 3 | F | 2 |
```

As you can see, the individuals don't have necessarily the same number of multiple samples. Yeah non-consistent field work! An acceptable way to do this using regex or R would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you want is `merge`. If those are read in as two `data.frame` objects in R then you just:

```
merge(dataframe1, dataframe2)
```

All you have to do is make sure that the `Ind` column has the same name in both.

Comment: data.table, match and %in% can join two datasets faster (match and %in% are slightly different).